# Dapper doesn't map CTE rows

Tags: sql, mapping, dapper

I have query with CTE and want to map output to class

```
with t as (SELECT
               (SELECT value from group_attribute ga2 WHERE ga2.group_id = kg.id AND ga2.name = 'description') as group_description,
               kg.id AS group_id,
               kg.name AS name,
               kg.parent_group AS parent_group,
               kg.realm_id AS realm_id,
               ga.id AS group_attr_id,
               ga.name AS group_attr_name,
               ga.value AS group_attr_value,
               ga.value AS group_attr_group_id
           FROM keycloak_group kg
                    JOIN group_attribute ga ON ga.group_id = kg.id AND ga.name = 'CompanyId'
           WHERE ga.value = '7bc5672e-9fb9-43f2-ab2e-da03dca0c32d'
           UNION
           SELECT
               (SELECT value from group_attribute ga2 WHERE ga2.group_id = kg.id AND ga2.name = 'description') as group_description,
               kg.id AS group_id,
               kg.name AS name,
               kg.parent_group AS parent_group,
               kg.realm_id AS realm_id,
               ga.id AS group_attr_id,
               ga.name AS group_attr_name,
               ga.value AS group_attr_value,
               ga.value AS group_attr_group_id
           FROM keycloak_group kg
                    JOIN group_attribute ga ON ga.group_id = kg.id
           WHERE  ga.name = 'isCommon' and ga.value = 'true')
SELECT DISTINCT  COUNT(*) over (partition by t.group_id) as members_count, (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) over (partition by 1) from t) as total_count,t.*
FROM t
            JOIN user_group_membership ugm ON ugm.group_id = t.group_id
```

And I have class entity for row

```
public class RoleEntityV2
{
    [Column("members_count")]
    public int MembersCount { get; set; }

    [Column("total_count")]
    public string TotalCount { get; set; }

    [Column("group_description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    [Column("group_id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Querying like that

```
        var result = await connection.QueryAsync<RoleEntityV2>(query, new
        {
            tenantKey = request.TenantKey, 
         
        });
```

But when query executes, values are default or null.

[image]

But when I change query execution to `await connection.QueryAsync<dynamic>` - they are persisted in output.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the output from the `dynamic` version, we see that the columns are things like `group_id`, `group_description`, etc. The only one that looks similar is `name`, and `name`/`Name` *worked* in the original query. Dapper cares about column names, **and doesn't use `[Column(...)]`**. If you want to map these columns, you'll *either* need to change the POCO so that the columns align, or change the query to include column aliases.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I've figured it with custom map provider function.